# Samsung Galaxy S4, weird model, can I custom ROM?

Tags: custom-roms

I just got my S4, on a Canadian network. While everyone seems to have I9500, I have the M919V. It's next to impossible to find any useful information on Google regarding this model. Can I use the same custom ROMs as the I9500 users?

There is a way! Read my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out more about this variant! Hopefully this helps people in my situation.

This device is on a Canadian network called Wind Mobile. The model M919V can use the same roms as the T-Mobile variant, which is M919.

I have flashed CyanogenMod nightlies on it, it runs awesome, and even for a nightly it is very battery efficient and stable.

Strongly recommend it to anyone.

I had to use ouhds instead of ClockWorkRecovery (they re the same things though). It still goes through Odin, but you will have to follow the instruction online. There are a few sets of instructions that can be found through Google.

These are the instructions I followed:

http://droidviews.com/2013/root-and-install-cwm-recovery-on-sprint-galaxy-s4-sph-l720-and-t-mobile-galaxy-s4-sgh-m919/

*I am not responsible for any damage you cause to your device, just sharing my thoughts/ experience.

Answer (score 1):

No, since your model number differs - meaning you have a carrier bound device - ROMs meant for standard i9500 devices won't be suited to your device.